# Test selector for all tests in includes plus some extra (JUnit5+Surefire)

Tags: junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

How do I run all tests from the explicitly specified `include`s in `pom.xml` as well as some additional test class not contained in the `include`s.

In other words, I'm looking for one command to select:

1. all tests that would be normally executed in the standard `mvn test` run
2. a separate test class explicitly specified in the argument ExtraTestClass

something along the lines of: `mvn test -Dtest="includes,ExtraTestClass"`

or

`mvn test && mvn test -Dtest="ExtraTestClass"`

Is that possible or would I have to adjust the names of all tests included in the standard `mvn test` run to fit a pattern?